# Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.apache.http.HttpResponse

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I'm trying to update a MySQL data in Android by making HTTP Request but it gives me an error

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.apache.http.HttpResponse to com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse"

on this line of code "httpClient.execute(httpPost)"

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

and it gives and option to quick fix by adding org.apache.http like

```
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thank you so much!

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://---.com/---/approve_request.php");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", "Approved"));

    try {
          httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {              
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

           try {
              org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);  
              Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());

         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {             
              e.printStackTrace();

         } catch (IOException e) {              
              e.printStackTrace();

         }

    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have wrong import statement in your code.

goto top of your class and look for

`import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse`

replace it with

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;`
instead of `import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;`

Answer (score 2):

```
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

     InputStream is = null;
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", "Approved"));


        try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                ""http://---.com/---/approve_request.php"");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be having

```
    import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
```

in your imports list at the top of the source code.

Please update that to

```
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;.
```

`httpClient.execute(httpPost);` is returning `org.apache.http.HttpResponse` object and by having incorrect import type, you are trying to cast it to `com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse`, which is cause the issue.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the help

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.http.HttpResponse` and `com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse` are two completely separate and different Java classes. You cannot just simply take one and convert it to the other. If you are using Apache's `HttpClient`, then it will always return `org.apache.http.HttpResponse`, not the Android version. If you indeed want to use Apache's HttpClient, then I suggest you just stick to the Apache version instead of the Android version of HttpResponse and extract headers/content directly as needed.